# Is it a sin for a job holder wife not taking proper care of husband and child?

Tags: sin, family, husband-wife

If a wife is a doctor who works outside, thus cannot take care of her husband and child properly. Will it be sin? When the situation is that the profession of the wife is hampering her duty towards her family, can the husband stop his wife from doing outside job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be several points concerning what you inquired:

> Is it a sin for a job holder wife not taking proper care of husband
>   and child

Such as:

- Based on Islamic evidences, (at least based on Shia’s viewpoint), it
  is permissible for women (wives) to work out of the house (by
  observing some items…, aside from some limitations in doing that…)
- The husband cannot force or make the wife to do the house’s works
  (although it is better if the wife do the works herself without
  forcing…). In the meantime, it shows how much Islam pay attention to
  women rights…

According to Imam Khomeini (Ayatollah Khomeini) as a Shiite Marja’-al-Taqlid as the response to the following question as it has been asked:

> If the husband didn’t deem it (working of wife out of the home)
>   advisable, and being employed of wife causes to break up the married
>   life, “can the husband prevent her wife to work or not?”
>
> Imam Khomeini (Ayatollah Khomeini) replied:
>
> Being employed for the wife is no impermissible, but it is related to
>   the right (permission) of the husband if she wants to get out of the
>   house.

For more info. I strongly recommend you to read the reference below which relatively is considered as a perfect relevant source. (If you are familiar with Farsi (Persian))

---

**Reference:**

[www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%BA%D8%A7%D9%84_%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86)

Comment: I dont see any straight cut answer here. Again husband cant force wife to do household work then what a women should do? she is not responsible for earning , she is not responsible for household work. Does islam tells woman to sit idle whole life if they wish?

Comment: Uh, no dear Zahan. It doesn't mean that. Haply it seems Islam ask the wife to do the works of home freely not in force. Besides, there are lot of reward (thawab) for working of wife based on the hadiths. But as I told you before, Islam wants to shows the wife that she is not limited a lot...

Comment: Besides, dear mate, you'd better notice to the mentioned quotation that said "...but it is related to the right (permission) of the husband if she wants to get out of the house", what does it mean? it can be inferred from it that Islam ask the wife (indirectly) to be under the permission of her husband as it is said that "the wife needs her husband's permission if she intends to get out of home". Then I reckon it doesn't mean what first you inferred. I admire your paying attention to this nice point. I am at your service dear mate for more question as much as I know... good luck.

Comment: Thnx a lot @Seyyed . It become very clear now to me. All praise to allah to gave us such nice solution to lead a life of love and peace.

Comment: uh-huh, now you are right. I'm glad that you didn't look at the mentioned matter on bias. God Bless You. Good luck dear mate.